# Write table to multiple database connections using pipes

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr, rsqlite, r-dbi

I've created two sqlite databases, and I'd like to use the magrittr/dplyr piping convention to write a single data frame to each dabatabse.

```
conn1 <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "db1")
conn2 <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "db2")

iris %>%
 DBI::dbWriteTable(conn1, "iris", .) %>%  # works
 DBI::dbWriteTable(conn2, "iris", .)      # does not work because lhs is not a table
```

Another (failed) attempt, because `dbWriteTable` only accepts a single connection

```
iris %>%
 DBI::dbWriteTable(c(conn1, conn2), "iris", .)
```

I prefer a solution that utilizes a pipe variation, perhaps a variation that retains the output from `iris`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal pipe operator `%>%` passed along the result of the previous function to the next. The `DBI::dbWriteTable` function returns `TRUE` if it works. It does not re-pass along the data.frame that was passed to it

If you import `magrittr` you can instead use the "tee" operator `%T>%`. This essentially throws away whatever the previous function returns and just passes along the original input again. For example

```
iris %T>%
 DBI::dbWriteTable(conn1, "iris", .) %T>%
 DBI::dbWriteTable(conn2, "iris", .)
```

See the [magrittr documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) for more information about the tee operator.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to MrFlicks comment, you can just use `purrr` or the `apply` family of functions for iteration over a list of connections using `walk`, which iterates over a list using functions typically called for their side effects.

```
library(DBI)
library(purrr)

conn1 <- dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "db1")
conn2 <- dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "db2")

connections <- list(conn1, conn2)

walk(connections, ~dbWriteTable(.x, "iris", iris))
```

Comment: unable to reproduce this successfully...`Error: Index 1 must be a character or numeric vector`

Comment: This works on my setup, running the above code.  You may be writing to an existing table, which is throwing a type mismatch error.